# CURL and redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl

CURL and redirect

Hi.

I am using CURL to check some sites. I am having problems with some redirects. Not every time, just a few cases.

In this case, I have a 302 code, but the redirect URL is the same as the original URL.

Dump of CURL variables:

```
array(23) {
["url"]=> string(33) "http://www.apostasurpresa.gov.br/"
["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
["http_code"]=> int(302) 
["header_size"]=> int(180) 
["request_size"]=> int(92) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.037685) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.000171) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.018808) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.01882) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.037521) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_url"]=> string(33) "http://www.apostasurpresa.gov.br/"
["primary_ip"]=> string(15) "200.201.166.106" 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Curl page:

```
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST ,'GET');
//      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  // true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 6);// 3 => 6
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
$txt_pagina = curl_exec($ch); 
$info=curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
 and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1) with tje same result.

Comment: What happens if you visit the page in the browser? Do you think it may be the server isn't happy with your user agent and is therefore redirecting back in a loop?  Try using a "real" browser's user agent string...

Comment: Redirect to http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/.

Comment: About the server, don't know. When I run this program I check almost 1500 sites. Only a few have problems. Not sure, but I don't think the server is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, following up with an answer after the comments :)

I checked this with wget and it actually redirects to several places before landing on the portal page URL you provided above.

The original URL throws a 302, refers back to itself, then a 301.  Then the URL it redirects to gives a lot of javascript, and the javascript then does a redirect.

So your code isn't working because it isn't parsing the javascript to redirect...

So... the solution. Why not just point to the portal page instead of dealing with multiple redirects?  BTW the portal redirects if the URL doesn't end with a / so use http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/ as your URL.

Comment: This is a solution, it works.
But ...
I have a official list of government registered domains, and this is my star point. 
If I change from www.apostasurpresa.gov.br to loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias, and they change this redirect tomorrow, I will check the wrong domain. 
One thing I am checking is redirect that go to the same page. 

But thanks to put more light on the problem.